# inconsistency in VB.Net compiler?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, controller

At the moment I am suffering from the most strange compler error messages I have ever seen.
I have a straightforward .Net framework 4.5.1 type library where I have about 40 controllers. They all are generated by the wizard. Only small changes made in order to have the right funtionality.

Now the (pre)compiler generates error messages in 5 out of all controllers:

There are 2 kind of messages:
1. Type IHttpActionResult is not defined
2. Type ResponseType is not defined

I don't understand why these errors would occur in only 5 out of all controllers. But the most extreme version is the controller where I get the messages inconsistently:

1. in the PUT statement nothing is wrong (no errors reported)
2. in the POST statement the ResponseType is "in error" and the IHttpActionResult is OK
3. in the DELETE statement both the ResponseType and the IHttpActionResult trigger the error. I will try to attach a copy of the page where these errors are illustrated.
   [image]
   Anyone any idea what is going on here???

Oh and almost forgot to mention: of course I have reinstalled Visual Studio 2013 Pro 4 by repairing it.

Comment: Have you imported `System.Web.Http`? And what happens if you use `System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult` instead?

Comment: Hi Vincent, thanks for your reaction. The imprts are all there, based on the wizard that puts them there. The second you mention is not possible to import. based on the options i get when setting the Imports command. I even wonder if it is at all possible to set a reference to an interface in the fashion you describe...?

Comment: Oh, haha. I didn't mean that you should import the IHttpActionResult. Sorry for being unclear. I was wondering what would happen if you used `As Task(Of System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult)` instead. :)

Comment: Thanks Visual Vincent for this reaction. In the mean time I have reconstructed the Solution and re-imported the projects. Problem disappeared....

Comment: Strange, but good. (: